# how to add namespace to all module's build.gradle Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, namespaces

After I updated my gradle to 8.0 , I got error namespace when build apk event if I have set the namespace in android build.gradle

this my build gradle code

**build.gradle:android/app**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()//33
    namespace 'com.appidname.here'
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appidname.here"
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()//21
        targetSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.targetSdkVersion').toInteger()//33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
     ....
}
```

**build.gradle:android**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.22'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
....
```

this is the error I got when buil apk or appbuble.

**Error**

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':webview_pro_android'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

     android {
         namespace 'com.example.namespace'
     }
```

from the error I think namespace don't set in all plugin modules yet.
how to solve this, how to add namespace to all plugin modules?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution

add this code in **project gradle** file:

```
subprojects{
    afterEvaluate {
        android {
            namespace 'add your namespace here'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `build.gradle` file look a like this.

```
android {
    namespace 'your_package_name'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your_package_name"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: I have add it there. you can look to my code above. That is still getting error namespace as well.

Comment: Need Proper Explanation

Comment: It's fine but, in all packages/modules expecting the namespace in Flutter. How to resolve this?

Comment: I removed android sdk 34 and install sdk 33. because my android studio is giraffe.
and I change in build.gradle:android dependencies to com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2

I think if you want use android sdk 34, you have to use new android studio version (above giraffe version)